# Multiple authentication not working passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate multiple user through multiple strategies. I have 2 table first is User table and second is employee but it's working when i try to login it show the error

```
     User not exist
```

when i use just single authentication strategy it's work but when i use multiple strategy it shows error

Auth.js

```
 const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
 const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
 const User = require('../models/authUserModel')
 const Employee = require('../models/employeeModel')
 module.exports = function (passport) {
      passport.use("user-local",
         new LocalStrategy({usernameField: "email"}, function (email, password, done) {   
           User.findOne({email: email})
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, ({message: 'Email not exist'}))
                }
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err
                    if (isMatch) {
                        return done(null, user)
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, ({message: 'Password incorrect'}))
                    }
                })
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))

    })
)
passport.use('local',
    new LocalStrategy({usernameField:"email"}, function (email, password, done){
        Employee.findOne({email:"email"})
            .then(user=>{
                if(!user){
                    return done(null, false,'employee not exist')
                }
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
                    if(isMatch){
                        return done(null, user)
                    }
                    else {
                        return done(null, false, 'password or email is incorrect')
                    }
                })
            }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
    })
)

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);

});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

}

Login.js

```
  let express = require('express');
  let router = express.Router();
  const passport = require('passport')



  router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('login');
  })
  router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
     passport.authenticate("user-local", function (err, user, info) {
     if (err) {
        return next(err)
     }
     if (!user) {
     console.log('User not exist')
        return res.render('login')
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
           return next(err)
        }  
        req.session.isLoggedIn = true
        req.session.user = user
        req.session.save(err => {
            console.log(err)
            if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
               return res.redirect('/customerMenu')
            }
            console.log('user not exist')
            return res.render('login')
         })
      })
  })(req, res, next)

passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info){

 if(err){
   return next(err)
}
if(!user)
{
  console.log("employee not exist")
  return res.render('login')
}

req.logIn(user,function (err){

  if(err){return next(err)}

  req.session.isLoggedIn = true

  req.session.user = user

  req.session.save(err=>{


    console.log(err)

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

      return res.redirect(200,'/employeeMenu')

    }

    console.log('user not exist')

    return res.render('login')

  })
})

  })(req, res, next)
 })
 function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
     if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.isLogged = true
        return next();
     }
     else{
       req.isLogged = false
       return next()
     }
 }
 module.exports = isLoggedIn
 module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to edit your `.serializeUser()` and `.deserializeUser()` functions so that passport knows what type of user you are trying to serialize and deserialize.

The way I have done it in the past is by using a SessionConstructor that puts both the user's id and the type of user they are inside an object. You can then use this in your deserialize function to figure out which usertype you are trying to sign in.

```js
function SessionConstructor(userId, userGroup){
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userGroup = userGroup;
}

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    let userGroup = 'user';
    if (//condition to tell if it is the other user type){
        userGroup = 'employee';
    };
    let sessionConstructor = new SessionConstructor(user.id, userGroup)

    done(null, sessionConstructor);
});

passport.deserializeUser((sessionConstructor, done) => {
    if (sessionConstructor.userGroup == 'user'){
        User.findById(sessionConstructor.userId).then(user => done(null, user));
    } else if (sessionConstructor.userGroup == 'employee'){
        Employee.findById(sessionConstructor.userId).then( employee=> done(null, employee));
    }
});
```

You will however need to think of a condition for the if statement inside of `.serializeUser()` that will tell you which type of user it is. If you include a unique identifier inside of the user object that is sent to `.serializeUser()`, then you can check that to tell. For example have a key called employee inside your user object where the value is `true` if its an employee submitting it, and `false` otherwise. If you choose this implementation it would look something like this.

```js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    let userGroup = 'user';
    if (user.employee){
        userGroup = 'employee';
    };
    let sessionConstructor = new SessionConstructor(user.id, userGroup)

    done(null, sessionConstructor);
});
```

Outisde of that I think the below code should work, but feel free to ask any questions about this method and I'll do my best to answer!

[Here is a link to where I learned about how to do this.](https://mjvolk.com/implement-multiple-local-user-authentication-strategies-in-passport-js)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I follow the step that mention in the link and in your answer but still it show the error User not exist

Comment: It show the error user not exist employee not exist but they both exist in db

Comment: So is the error happening inside of your deserialize user function? when you run `User.findById(sessionConstructor.userId)`

Comment: Thanks my friend for help now code work. The issue was in my passport authentication.